# What is the difference when a service is registered as a normal service vs ServiceFactory in OSGi container?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

What is the difference between registering a service as a normal service vs making it a ServiceFactory?

For example :

I have a normal osgi-component which I am making a service using service scr annotation

```
@Component 
@Service 
class Service1 implements Service1Interface { 
...
... 
... 
}
```

Now, I have another osgi-component which I will be registering as service with ServiceFactory flag as true

```
@Component 
@Service(serviceFactory=true )
class Service1 implements Service1Interface { 
...
... 
... 
}
```

What exactly is the difference between these two? Is there any difference when they are registered in the container and in what scenario's should we go for a ServiceFactory?

Answer (score 5):

In the former, there will be one instance of the component that will be used for all bundles that get the service. In the latter case, a new instance of the component will be created for each bundle that gets the service.

A service factory is useful if you need to track resources on a per using bundle basis.